# Scroll to Top on mm-subopen click

Tags: jquery, mmenu

Using mmenu and I'd like to scroll to top of the page whenever someone clicks on the "arrow" for the subpages; the a href class is named "mm-subopen".

It doesn't have an ID, so I have to go with the class.

How do I accomplish this?  I've tried the following, but it doesn't work.

Thanks..

```
$(function() {
  $("a.mm-subopen").scrollToTop(100);
});
```

Comment: Correct method is `.scrollTop()`, not `.scrollToTop()`, if you're using jQuery method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have forgotten to bind the click event to your selector. You will need to tell jQuery which event, when triggered from the element of interest, triggers the scrolling to top function. It is also advisable to disable the default function of the `<a>` element, by using `.preventDefault()`.

```
$(function() {
    $("a.mm-subopen").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(window).scrollTop(100);
    });
});
```

Also, we are scrolling the viewport, so we bind the `.scrollTop()` method to the `$(window)` object. See proof-of-concept demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/c1jvzvz7/

p/s: You have specified the viewport to scroll to the 100px position from the top. If you want to scroll to the true top, use `scrollTop(0)` instead.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  I ended up having to place this within a '$(document).ready(function' at the bottom of my DotNetNuke skin (along with other functions), but after this, all worked well.  Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: @user1424532 Actually, `$(function() {...});` is the equivalent of `$(document).ready(function() {...});`. The former is simply a shorthand :)